Using the formal definition to show that the sequence $u_n=n^{1/n}$ converges to $1$
I would like to prove this statement using the definition of a converging sequence. Is this correct ? Thank you for your time.
Let $\left( u_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\star}}$ be the sequence defined by $u_n=n^{1/n}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Clearly $u_n \geqslant 1$ for any integer $n \geqslant 1$. We have that
$$ n^{1/n} < 1+\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow n < \left( 1+\epsilon  \right) ^n = 1+n \epsilon + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon ^2 +   \ldots + \epsilon ^n $$
The binomial sum is $> 0$ therefore it suffices to show that
$$ n< \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon ^2 \Longleftrightarrow n>1+\frac{2}{\epsilon ^2} $$
Take $N \in \mathbb{N}^{\star}$ such that $N>1+2/\epsilon ^2$. If $ n \geqslant N$ then
$$ 1 \leqslant n^{1/n} < 1+\epsilon \Longrightarrow \left| n^{1/n} - 1 \right| < \epsilon$$
This shows that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} u_n = 1 \quad \blacksquare $$

It is correct to me!  Your key point is  that $$n< \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon ^2\implies n < \left( 1+\epsilon  \right) ^n\iff n^{1/n}<1+\epsilon.$$

Yes exactly. This is the important part of the proof I'd say
